# Подбор суммируемых констант

Tags: php

Необходимо сделать константы по сумме которых можно было бы определить что там лежит, как пример можно рассмотреть PHP JSON CONSTANT https://www.php.net/manual/ru/json.constants.php.

**Описание:** 
Нужно что-то вроде

```
1 - тип 1;
2 - тип 2;
3 - тип 3;
10 - возвращено на доработку;
20 - направлено на проверку;
100 - повторно;
```

**Задача**

Быстр вычислить из значения по какой-то формуле, что туда закодировано.

Прошу подсказать куда копать. может есть какие то готовое решения или формулы и правила формирования таких констант, желательно на `PHP`.

Comment: Куда копать - битовые маски и битовые операции. Достаточно итоговое число побитово (через "&") сравнить с одной из констант - чтобы можно было определить возможность данной операции http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/48c2a3fa8b55e24006ed2c08d5c304548dec3adf

Comment: @Сергей Мишин Не подскажите, что я делаю не так?http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/48c2a3fa8b55e24006ed2c08d5c304548dec3adf

Comment: Вы мне дали ссылку на то, что я вам прислал))

Comment: @Сергей Мишин http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e7cc4ee2a0ee1ed58d68ca43d52db8dbb7c3263a

Comment: Битовые операции валидны только для тех чисел, что в десятичном виеде кратны двум, т.е. 1,2,4,8,16,64 и т.д. Потому что, в двоичном виде они будут представлять из себя числа `00000001` , `00000010`, `00000100` и т.д. Поэтому булева операция будет проходить успешно. См:  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7f74a7e9bb8a02a53f68c7c6c798bc2bcb0ed39a    Для ваших же чисел, соответствено, по вышеуказанной причине это работать не будет. Моя рекомендация - сменить численное представления для типов. Это будет проще, чем пытаться написать что-то под данные числа

Comment: @Сергей Мишин СПАСИБО!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычным подходом является установка необходимых флагов в отдельных битах числа.

В вашем примере есть два вида флагов, условно говоря, тип (3 вида) и состояние (3 вида). Давайте устанавливать в младшие  `⌈log2(3)⌉ = 2` бита информацию о типе и в следующие `⌈log2(3)⌉ = 2` бита информацию о состоянии. Определим следующие константы:

```
const TYPE1 = 0b00000000;
const TYPE2 = 0b00000001;
const TYPE3 = 0b00000010;

const STATE1 = 0b00000000;
const STATE2 = 0b00000100;
const STATE3 = 0b00001000;
```

Далее, для получения значения, кодирующего оба состояния, возьмём битовую сумму констант каждого вида:

```
$result = TYPE2 | STATE3;  // 0b00001001
```

Теперь, чтобы обратно узнать, какие флаги были выставлены, битово умножим получившееся значение на необходимую маску:

```
switch ($result & 0b00001100) {
    case STATE1:
        //
        break;
    case STATE2:
        //
        break;
    case STATE3:
        //
        break;
    default:
        echo 'error value';
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2024a763d84c6d8bd324545e78bd27d1eeddd869

---

Заметьте, что 8-битные числа были использованы для примера. В реальных программах можно использовать 32-битные или 64-битные числа в зависимости от системы.

---

В PHP 7.4, кстати, [реализовано](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/numeric_literal_separator) разделение цифр числа подчёркиванием. Так что можно написать:

```
const TYPE1 = 0b0000_00_00;
const TYPE2 = 0b0000_00_01;
const TYPE3 = 0b0000_00_10;

const STATE1 = 0b0000_00_00;
const STATE2 = 0b0000_01_00;
const STATE3 = 0b0000_10_00;
```

Comment: именно то, что я искал, а можно сделать это как-то в типе int для более удобного восприятия и хранения в базу данных?

Comment: @AlexKnow, так это в типе int. Просто числа записаны в двоичной записи как раз для более удобного восприятия. Вы можете записать их в десятичной системе счисления, только тогда смысл значений будет неочевиден. А при использовании констант вам не нужно вообще знать, как оно там записано.

Comment: Я понял Вас, что это int просто в двоичной, я о следующем, есть необходимость хранить эти значения в базе в типе int, для sql запросов, но если я делаю преобразование из int в двоичную строку по средствам функции `decbin`, то всё перестаёт работать.

Comment: Причём здесь строка? Ничего не надо преобразовывать. Один раз пропишите константы и используйте. Если вы не знали, числа в памяти и так хранятся в битах.

Comment: Наверное я неправильно выразился, вот что я имею в виду, [ссылка](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca5bd58a965a7b6bce7bcd51bc5bff9aa7e6152d) по всей видимости, я делаю что то не так, но не пойму, что)

Comment: @AlexKnow, а как этот код вообще связан с моим ответом? Откуда значения 1, 2, 3, 10, 100?

Comment: Ну данные числа я взял из своего вопроса, просто данные уже есть в базе, и встал вопрос при формирование html страницы выводить тот или иной текст по этим данным

Comment: @AlexKnow, с вашими значениями этот способ не сработает. В ответе указано, как именно нужно задавать значения константам.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.